# Why is "citrus" uncountable in one dictionary and countable in another?

Tags: countability

Why is the word "citrus" uncountable in [the Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/citrus):

> [uncountable]
> fruit belonging to the group of fruit that includes oranges, lemons, limes and grapefruit:
> *citrus trees*
> *citrus fruit*

and countable in [the Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/citrus):

> [countable] (plural: "citrus" or "citruses")
> any of a group of plants that produce acidic fruits with a lot of juice:
> *The field was planted with citrus trees*.
> *Oranges, lemons, limes and grapefruit are types of citrus fruit*.

How is it possible that in the same collocations ("*citrus trees*" and "*citrus fruit*"), one dictionary says the word is uncountable and another says it's countable?

Comment: Interesting find! Some words that are considered uncountable can be used in the plural to indicate different types of that thing, like "cheese", while other uncountable words cannot be used as plurals at all, like "education". It may be that the editors at one dictionary decided that any ability to use the word as a plural makes the word countable, while the other dictionary's editors decided it doesn't. Check both dictionaries for nouns that are normally uncountable but can be used in the plural to indicate types, and see if there's a consistent pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The collocations that you mentioned involve grammatical constructions that don't distinguish between uncountable and countable uses: "citrus" in "citrus trees" and "citrus fruit" is either an attributive noun or an adjective. Attributive nouns are not used in the plural form (aside from certain exceptions) and adjectives do not have plural forms.

The fact of the matter is that "citrus", like many words, has uses both as a count noun and as a non-count noun:

- Count use:

> Bergamot is a **citrus** classified as *Citrus bergamia* Risso which belongs to genus Citrus, family Rutaceae and is defined as a hybrid of *Citrus aurantium* and *Citrus limon* L.

("[Bergamot (*Citrus bergamia*) Oils](https://books.google.com/books?id=uNDUBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA247)", by Raúl Avila-Sosa et al., chapter 27 in *Essential Oils in Food Preservation, Flavor and Safety,* edited by Victor R. Preedy, page 247)

- Non-count use:

> Industry representatives have noted that Cuba could export enough **citrus** 6 to 8 weeks ahead of the first U.S. production to depress prices for the whole U.S. season.

([The Economic Impact of U.S. Sanctions with Respect to Cuba, USITC Publication 3398, Investigation No. 332-413,](https://books.google.com/books?id=c0wCioRlTG0C&pg=SA5-PA32) page 5-32)

I don't know why the cited dictionaries don't just both say "countable or uncountable".